# Avoiding null errors when mixing scriptlet and script tags in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have inherited some code which is causing a minor issue and it has made me realise there is a whole are of jsp coding I've managed to completely avoid up to now...  I'd love to unsertand how it is actually working and ideally get a fix (I can always fix it in the back end java MVC app by navigating to an 'item not found' page if necessary)

In may JSP page there is some scriptlet code accessing underlying java code to instantiate an object

```
<%@ page import="com..."%>
....

<%
    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();   
    AccountOverview accountOverview=(AccountOverview )request.getAttribute("accountOverview");
    FacetedSubAccountsResultBean facetedSubAccountsResultBean = null;

    if ( accountOverview != null ) {
        facetedSubAccountsResultBean =(FacetedSubAccountsResultBean )accountOverview.getSubAccountsResult();            
    }
 %>
```

It then goes straight into script to get some values (I've split this out in quite a convoluted way while debugging)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = <%=ow.writeValueAsString(facetedSubAccountsResultBean)%>;
    var facetsJson;
    var selectedFacetString;

    //alert (x);  null when accountOverview is null

    if (x){
       alert ('comes in here when there is a value');
       facetsJson=<%=ow.writeValueAsString(facetedSubAccountsResultBean.getFacetGroups())%>;
    selectedFacetString=<%=ow.writeValueAsString(facetedSubAccountsResultBean.getRequest().getSelectedFacets())%>;
  }
else {
  alert ('comes in here when null - fires if the two <%= lines above are commented out');
}
```

If the accountOverview object exists this works fine.  If it is null it fails with a java.lang.NullPointerException.  If I comment out

```
facetsJson=<%=ow.writeValueAsString(facetedSubAccountsResultBean.getFacetGroups())%>;
    selectedFacetString=<%=ow.writeValueAsString(facetedSubAccountsResultBean.getRequest().getSelectedFacets())%>;
```

Then I get the alert in the correct path -'comes in here when null - fires if the two <%= lines above are commented out'

I'm guessing (?) that the code in <% %> is accessed when the page is rendered even though this path is not used ?  Is that the cause ?  Is there a simple way of testing the value and thus allowing a later choice between object rendering or a simple "Doesn't exist" message on the page ?

I'm not sure if I have been clear here or just convoluted !?